# Use netsh advfirewall to Add windows 7 firewall exception

Tags: windows-7, netsh

Hi
I am adding a firewall exception to Windows 7 using netsh.
The simple rule i am adding is:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name = "The Test App3" dir = in action = allow description = "Smart Cipher inbound messages" program = "C:\temp\a.exe"
```

The problem is that after executing this command a new rule is added to the firewall and is displayed within the firewall console - but it seems it is not properly configured for two reasons:
1. The *Remove* button in the firewall console is disabled 
2. Clicking the *Details...*  button show no details for the rule, unlike other "good rules", but only name and description

Please advice

Tx

Oren

Answer (score 1):

added only profiles arguments to yours command line also removed all those spaces ...="... all works fine.

ps: Vikram.exe: default is enabled=yes (true)

here is what I got at the end:

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Visaris Diagon 3.1
>   Administration" dir=in action=allow profile=any description="Visaris
>   Diagon 3.1 Administration" program="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Visaris\Visaris Diagon 3.1\Visaris.Diagon.Administration.exe"
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Visaris Diagon 3.1
>   Administration" dir=out action=allow profile=any description="Visaris
>   Diagon 3.1 Administration" program="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Visaris\Visaris Diagon 3.1\Visaris.Diagon.Administration.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "enable" sub command and removing the spaces

eg:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="The Test App3" dir=in action=allow
description="Smart Cipher inbound messages" program="C:\temp\a.exe" enable=yes
```

Comment: Thanks but 
adding "enable=yes" and removing spaces didn't help...